# Add a date or a number at the end of a slug

Tags: python, django, wagtail

i'm trying to add a number or publish date at the end of a slug, off the page mode, if the slug already exist.
I found a possible solution with RoutablePageMixin but not quite sure how to approach it as it changes the URL not the slug itself.

Here is what i got so far but it seams that is not working...

```
class BlogPage(HeadlessPreviewMixin, Page):
#...

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call the built-in cleanups (including default slug generation)
        super(BlogPage, self).full_clean(*args, **kwargs)

        # now make your additional modifications
        if not self.slug.startswith('awesome'):
            self.slug = "awesome-%s" % self.slug
```

Comment: Are you trying to "rename" what you have in the slug field in the DB?

Comment: @HigorRossato I would like to get a unique slug every time on page publish, thats the goal.

Comment: `self.slug = "awesome-%s" % datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%H:%M")` this would be an option. maybe add an ID to make it truely unique becuase if two people add one at the same time you have a problem...

Comment: @hansTheFranz This method is not working as it renames the slug after save.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to achieve can be done on the `.save()` of the model.

## models.py

```
import datetime as dt


class BlogPage(...):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        if self.slug:
            self.slug = f"{self.slug}-{now.isoformat()}"
        super().save(self, **kwargs)
```

OR you can do this...

## views.py

```
class BlogPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    # Multiple routes!
    @route(r'^$')
    @route(r'^year/(\d+)/$')
    def events_for_year(self, request, year=None):
        ...
```

Comment: With this i'm getting a Validation error `{'slug': ['Enter a valid “slug” consisting of Unicode letters, numbers, underscores, or hyphens.']}`

Comment: I think (after reading a bit on the wagtail docs) that you don't need to change anything on your models.py. What you want, as you already have described, can be done through views.py. Have a look [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html#the-basics)